# Oracle SQL Developer 3.2.09 is consuming lot of memory on windows 7

Tags: oracle-sql-developer

Oracle SQL Developer  Version 3.2.09 is consuming lot of memory on windows 7.

I can see, after 1/2 days of usage and without closing the this application, the memory consumption is going upto 700 MB.

So, in this case, I need to close the application and again restart.

Any remedies for this can be helpful.

Details of SQL Developer are:

```
Oracle SQL Developer  Version 3.2.09

Build MAIN-09.30
```

JDK we are using is `JDK 1.6`

Comment: SQLDev 3.2 is pretty old... I would start out by downloading the latest version of SQLDev: 4.1.3 and JDK 8 from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html.  Keep in mind that SQLDev 4.1.3 is still a monster memory hog, so check the following on how to improve the performance of SQLDev and configure its memory usage: http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2011/12/top-10-preferences-to-tweak-when-using-sql-developer/ and http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/06/configuring-memory-usage-in-oracle-sql-developer/

Answer (score 2):

Add below lines to `C:\Users\<<user>>\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper\4.2.0\product.conf`

For 64 bit SQL Developer add:

```
Add64VMOption -XX:+UseG1GC
Add64VMOption -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=15
Add64VMOption -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=30
```

For 32 bit SQL Developer add:

```
Add32VMOption -XX:+UseG1GC
Add32VMOption -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=15
Add32VMOption -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=30
```

Restart SQL Developer.

To reduce the memory close only the results pane that has huge result set.

TIP: I typically increase JVM memory to 2 GB so SQL Developer does not crash for queries with large result sets. This can be done by adding below line to `product.conf`:

```
Add64VMOption -Xmx2048m
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools--> Preferences-->Environment.

Change the "Look And Feel" value for Oracle to Windows.

Comment: Does this really help to fix memory consumption issues in SQL Developer?

Comment: To an extent. My memory utilisation has been reduced from .6 GB to .5 GB and been monitoring for a week now.

Comment: This worked great on my Mac

Answer (score 0):

That's the JVM and not SQL Developer.

You're running an old copy of SQL Developer and Java.

Go get Version 17.2 and Java 8 or 9 - it is much more performant/responsive on Windows and will do better garbage collection.

And even so, 700MB of RAM isn't very much for an IDE. Go take a look at what Chrome is using on your system now.